# Listen to AVPlayer timeControlStatus changes in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avplayer

So trying to implement as simple observer for AVPlayer in SwiftUI. I've added the observer which is triggered but haven't figured out how/where to implement `observeValue` as per the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/responding_to_playback_state_changes

So far I have my AVPlayer class as follows:

```
class Player: AVPlayer, ObservableObject {

    @Published var isPlaying: Bool = false

    static var shared = AVPlayer()
    static var episodeId: Int?

    static func playItem(at itemURL: String, episodeId: Int) {
        let url = URL(string: itemURL)
        Player.shared = AVPlayer(url: url!)
        Player.episodeId = episodeId
        Player.shared.addObserver(self.shared, forKeyPath: "timeControlStatus", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
    }
}
```

So the question is where I should implement this for it to work:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                           of object: Any?,
                           change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                           context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if Player.shared.timeControlStatus == .playing {
        // Set @Published isPlaying to true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can like the following (don't use `static` it's not needed in this case, anyway you'll be needed instance to use in `@ObservedObject`)

Of course it is not final `Player`, but the direction to evolve it should be clear:

```
class Player: AVPlayer, ObservableObject {

    @Published var isPlaying: Bool = false

    private var playerContext = 0

    var player: AVPlayer? = nil
    var episodeId: Int?

    func playItem(at itemURL: String, episodeId: Int) {
        guard let url = URL(string: itemURL) else { return }

        // cleanup for previous player
        self.player?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timeControlStatus")

        // setup new player
        let newPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
        newPlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timeControlStatus", options: [.old, .new], context: &playerContext)

        self.player = newPlayer
        self.episodeId = episodeId
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                               of object: Any?,
                               change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                               context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        guard context == &playerContext else { // give super to handle own cases
               super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath,
                       of: object,
                       change: change,
                       context: context)
               return
        }
        if self.player?.timeControlStatus == .playing {
            self.isPlaying = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried putting the observeValue in the class but getting “message received but not handled” error. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ismailp in your method `override func observeValue(forKeyPath..` call the `super.observeValue....` and then do your logic.